# Laravel Mail enviar parametros desde controller o desde

Tags: laravel, mail

estoy intentando enviar un email desde Laravel, pero para este proyecto preciso necesito enviar emails desde diferentes servidores SMTP que se cargan previamente en la base de datos.

tengo el siguiente código en el Mailable:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from(Settings::get('app_admin_email'), Settings::get('app_admin_email'))
    ->subject('Subject del Email')
    ->view('email');
}
```

Este código me funciona a la perfección llamandolo desde el controlador:

```
Mail::to('receptor@email.com')->send(new ContactReceived($data));
```

y carga el email del from desde la base de datos sin problema.

Pero ahora el tema es que necesito enviar los parametros del smtp cargandolos desde la base de datos, en lugar del archivo .env o de config/mail.php con como hago con el resto de los parametros. Settings::get('xxxxx')

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado:

```
use Config;

Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', Settings::get('app_mailserver_url'));
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', Settings::get('app_mailserver_url'));
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.encryption', Settings::get('app_mailserver_url'));
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', Settings::get('app_mailserver_url'));
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', Settings::get('app_mailserver_url'));
        Config::set('mail.from.address', Settings::get('app_mailserver_url'));
        Config::set('mail.from.name', Settings::get('app_mailserver_url'));
```

Con esta modificación logré cargar los datos desde la base de datos al parecer no me enviaba por el caché.